# Getting a progress for an FTP-upload with node

Tags: node.js, electron, node-ftp

I have an Electron app which uploads a dropped file to a predefined server with [node-ftp](https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp). The upload works like a charm, but despite reading a couple of suggestions I cannot figure out how to get information on the actual progress for a progress-bar.
My upload-code so far:

```
var ftp = new Client();
let uploadfile = fs.createReadStream(f.path);
let newname = uuid(); //some function I use for renaming

ftp.on('ready', function () {
    ftp.put(uploadfile, newname, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        ftp.end();
    });
});

c.connect({user: 'test', password: 'test'});
```

I always stumble across monitoring the 'data' event, but could not find out how or where to access it (as you can see I'm quite new to JavaScript).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Got it. I found the answer in [streams with percentage complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798047/streams-with-percentage-complete)

With my code changed to

```
var ftp = new Client();
let uploadfile = fs.createReadStream(f.path);
let newname = uuid(); //some function I use for renaming

ftp.on('ready', function() {
    uploadfile.on('data', function(buffer) {
        var segmentLength = buffer.length;
        uploadedSize += segmentLength;
        console.log("Progress:\t" + ((uploadedSize/f.size*100).toFixed(2) + "%"));
    });

    ftp.put(uploadfile, newname, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
            ftp.end();
    });
});
c.connect({user: 'test', password: 'test'});
```

I get the percentage uploaded in console. From here it's only a small step to a graphical output.

Comment: how to do the same thing for download? please advice

Answer (score 0):

on client side you can create a *byte count* for your upload stream (http://www.experts.exchange.com/questions/24041115/upload-file-on-ftp-with-progressbar-and-time-left.html)

- set lower limit of the progressbar to 0
- set upper limit to file length of upload file
- feed the progress bar with the byte count

(http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/24608048/how-do-i-count-bytecount-in-read-method-of-inputstream)

maybe you can use npm like `stream-meter` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-meter) or `progress-stream` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress-stream) and pipe your file stream through to feed the progressbar. i am not sure about that because i  do not know the internals of the npms. in `progress-stream` is a function `transferred()` that would fit exactly

a very accurate way is to have code on the server that gives feedback to the browser (http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/8480240/progress-bar-for-iframe-uploads)

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get it. My problem is less of how to get a Progress-Bar out of data, but much more of "how do I get the actual uploaded amount of data from the variables I have"? How can i access this Information? The provided examples are in Java not JavaScript, and the npm will work for sure but I could not find out how. Accuracy is btw not a problem - I just want to provide some visual feedback.